Dynamically Build Search Query using Elasticsearch .NET client 8.3
I am new to ElasticSearch. I have a query that works but the values are hardcoded. I need to update the query to use a list of strings in the 'should' clause. I am not finding much documentation for the dotnet client. Is there a way to pass the 'should' clause a list of strings instead of hardcoding them here?
public async Task<SearchResponse<SubmissionDto>> GetRapbacksAsync(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string destination)
        {
            ElasticsearchClient localClient = GetClient(destination);
            var rapbacks = await localClient.SearchAsync<SubmissionDto>(SUBMISSION_INDEX, s => s
                .Query(q => q
                    .Bool(b => b
                        .Should( // Changed Must to Should for OR condition
                            ss => ss.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Tot).Value("RBIHS".ToLower())),
                            ss => ss.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Tot).Value("RBMNT".ToLower())),
                            ss => ss.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Tot).Value("RBSCRM".ToLower())),
                            ss => ss.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Tot).Value("RBN".ToLower())),
                            ss => ss.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Tot).Value("RBSCVL".ToLower())),
                            ss => ss.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Tot).Value("RBRPT".ToLower())),
                            ss => ss.Term(tt => tt.Field(f => f.Tot).Value("RBRPTR".ToLower()))
                        )
                        .MinimumShouldMatch(1) // At least one of the Should conditions must match
                        .Must(
                            ss => ss.Range(rr => rr
                                .DateRange(dr => dr
                                    .Field(f => f.SubmissionCreation)
                                    .Gte(startDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
                                    .Lte(endDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
                                ))))).Size(MAX_DOCUMENTS).Sort(sort => sort
                    .Field(f => f.SubmissionCreation, d => d.Order(SortOrder.Desc)))
            );
            return rapbacks;
        }

I tried a bunch of queries from chat gpt however it keeps giving responses from the old NEST client. Not sure it has all the info on the dotnet client.

Something like this should do the trick, though you might want to look into using the Terms query instead if looking for any overlap of values in a single field.
await localClient.SearchAsync<SubmissionDto>("myindex", s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(sh =>
                values
                    .Select<string, Action<QueryDescriptor<SubmissionDto>>>(value => 
                        sh => sh.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.Tot).Value(value.ToLower()))
                    )
                    .ToArray()
            )
        )
    )
);

Here is an example of using a the aforementioned Terms query, a bit nicer to read:
await localClient.SearchAsync<SubmissionDto>("myindex", s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.Tot)
            .Terms(new TermsQueryField(values.Select(value => FieldValue.String(value)).ToArray()))
        )
    )
);


This doesn't seem to work. The query only picks up the last 'value' in the array of values. I will look into Terms also.

@TiffanyLynn Sorry about that, I have edited my answer, hopefully it works for you now. Remember to also add back in your following queries, I only did the tricky part for brevity. :)

@TiffanyLynn I also included an example of using the mentioned Terms query, it is a bit nicer to write and read, hope this helps.

thanks! I will have another elastic question coming shortly :-) @issung
